# error: cannot access zzeuq class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuq not found

Tags: android

I am facing this error in my project 
      here is my gradle build

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

Comment: trying to add external jar in project ?

Comment: no i am just using firebase authentication

Comment: more details plz...

Comment: here is my main activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with equal versioning may be going wrong just because of inequal versioning do like following,

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.0
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.0
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog


Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.0
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Comment: I just have given example for equal versioning, so please try with another version.

Answer (score 1):

make sure to have maven imported in your gradle, check the docs https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the same version of Api or use External .jar files

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the compile and target sdk number is the same as the app compat number.
like this

```
compileSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 26
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score -1):

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: Please add an explanation how and why this solves the question. It would be good as well to explain what the difference to the accepted answer is, as it isn't immediately obvious. Thanks!