# Cannot access zzeuqclass file error in Android studio firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

When I run my project, I get this error:

> "error: cannot access zzeuqclass file for google.android.gms.internal.zzeuq not found"

when I click on the error message, it takes me to this line of code:

```
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51238197/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: cannot access zzeuq class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuq not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238197/error-cannot-access-zzeuq-class-file-for-com-google-android-gms-internal-zzeuq)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **build.gradle (Project:your_project)** and update google-services

```
 dependencies {
        /...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
```

check google services version here

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Also check your dependencies at your **build.gradle(Module:app)**

for example, the firebase auth latest implementation should be

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

you can check the library versions [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=en)

Comment: I've already done that when I connected my project to firebase, what else do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your play service dependency version and if is it less than 15.0.0 like 12.0.1 then put it as freebase dependency.And add freebase database,Auth ui

Comment: if your  play service dependency version upper the 15.0.0 then you can use freebase latest dependency.